# how to get the proper xpath for date picker in selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i can see the below xpath exists but selenium pops up with the below error message

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="calendar-btn"]/small"}
```

Comment: Relevant _HTML_ and code trials please.

Comment: <small class="strict-c">03/14/2018 - 03/24/2018</small> this is the outer html path

Comment: date = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="calendar-btn"]/small')

Comment: If it isn't a wait issue, then I suspect the element is contained within a frame or iframe.  Selenium can only locate objects that are in the current context, and treats elements in a different frame/iframe as a different context.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure about the xpath and you checked that this path is locating one single node, being the one you needed, then it must be a matter of timing. Try using explicit wait.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.Xpath, '//*[@id="calendarbtn"]/small")))
```

Comment: There are only divs no iframe